# Reading html source in soup retrieved from selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
html_source=driver.page_source   
html = BeautifulSoup(html_source)
```

Why is html_source and html different . What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use calling BeautifulSoup just with one parameter, you parse document as an html one. If one tag is not an HTML valid one, its corrected and document will be modified. You can see [Beautiful Soup Specifying the parser to use](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use).

Comment: Thanks for info! My question is with respect to this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982176/parse-the-html-code-for-a-whole-webpage-scrolled-down. How do you think I can read the entire html in soup?

Answer (score 2):

`driver.get` is not like most other `get` methods, you only visit the page. You can then obtain the html by using `driver.page_source`:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried you said check edit above. Still the same issue

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Try reopening the instance (either interactive seession or script). This should work :) Perhaps you're looking at the `html` element and not the `soup` one.

Comment: Can you give example please? Sorry I am new to python.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Simply restart python and rerun this code, then inspect `soup`

Comment: My question is with respect to this other question's answer code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982176/parse-the-html-code-for-a-whole-webpage-scrolled-down.

Comment: "Tried doesn't work" is really useless to say. How is anyone supposed to help with that? If you don't describe what the issue is no one can help.

Comment: Sorry for mentioning details. It returned not the full html code I required. Thus, `driver.page_source` and  `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)` are different.

Comment: driver.page_source returns HTML, BeautifulSoup on the driver.page_source returns a **parsed object on the html**, pretty much an interface to interact with the html. What is the child element of <html>, find all <a> tags in html can be answered with the soup object. By definition `driver.page_source != BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info but issue is I want to parse the html code using soup elements given I reading from selenium. When I try to print using soup.prettify() it removes the some of the html code present in  driver.page_source. Does this make sense?