# Retrieving data from twitter with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am using this js/jquery to scroll down a twitter page:

```
var f = function(i) { if(i < 999999999999) {
       window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
       setTimeout(function(){f(i+1)}, 1000)
    }

}

f(1)
```

And by doing it, I would like to save the webpage and do an scrape on it. But the problem is that my browser stop working, because the huge amount of info. So I want to know if there's any way to go save the page in the process.

Comment: Why do you want to scrape the page instead of using the API?

Comment: because the api just has 1% of the data.

Comment: I just found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982176/parse-the-html-code-for-a-whole-webpage-scrolled-down