# How to get tweet id from Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, beautifulsoup

I saw this code [Parse the html code for a whole webpage scrolled down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982176/parse-the-html-code-for-a-whole-webpage-scrolled-down) but I don't want just the text, I want the id too. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use code from the answer you provided, you can get the tweet id like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
for tweet in soup.select("div.tweet"):
    print tweet['data-tweet-id']
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked just fine. (I had to put a try/except).